# My PWA doesn't appear as installable in Chrome for Android ONLY

Tags: android, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json, google-chrome-android

I have built a "PWA" that seems to be working properly on desktop environments. I can install it on my desktop PCs and Mac without any problem:

[image: image1]

Additionally, the requirements are also met (at this point in time [2021-05-11]):

[image: preview]

[image: preview values]

[PWA Builder results](https://www.pwabuilder.com/?url=https%3A%2F%2Ffanmixco.github.io%2Ftoastmasters-timer-material-design%2F) (94/100 at this point in time [2021-05-11]):

[image: results]

However, it's not appearing as installable in my Chrome for Android (Add to Home Screen? This is for the non-PWAS from my knowledge):

[image: fail installation]

And I know it's not my Chrome because I have another PWA that is showing it properly (Install app):

https://fanmixco.github.io/toastmasters-timer

[image: preview2]

And its results are poorer (because it's the previous edition and it's unsupported):

[image: old preview]

My app used to work before. The only significant change is that I added the `manifest` to the Windows app in the `related_applications` section (I removed it and didn't work). The new changes are related to increasing its performance and efficiency.

This is my latest `manifest` file:

```
{
  "dir": "ltr",
  "lang": "da",
  "name": "Toastmasters Timer",
  "scope": "/toastmasters-timer-material-design/",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "start_url": "https://fanmixco.github.io/toastmasters-timer-material-design/",
  "short_name": "TM Timer",
  "theme_color": "#ffffff",
  "description": "It's a simple PWA for helping Toastmasters all over the world to have an effective and productive Timer for their meetings. It was developed with JavaScript by The Leader Ship Toastmasters in Łódź, Poland.",
  "orientation": "any",
  "background_color": "#ffffff",
  "related_applications": [
    {
      "platform": "play",
      "url": "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tk.supernova.tmtimer.tk.supernova.tmtimer",
      "id": "tk.supernova.tmtimer.tk.supernova.tmtimer"
    },
    {
      "platform": "windows",
      "url": "https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/toastmasters-timer-pro/9n9rhqms0nwg"
    }
  ],
  "prefer_related_applications": true,
  "generated": "true",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square71x71Logo.scale-400.png",
      "sizes": "284x284"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square71x71Logo.scale-200.png",
      "sizes": "142x142"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square71x71Logo.scale-100.png",
      "sizes": "71x71"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square71x71Logo.scale-150.png",
      "sizes": "107x107"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square71x71Logo.scale-125.png",
      "sizes": "89x89"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square150x150Logo.scale-400.png",
      "sizes": "600x600"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square150x150Logo.scale-200.png",
      "sizes": "300x300"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png",
      "sizes": "150x150"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square150x150Logo.scale-150.png",
      "sizes": "225x225"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square150x150Logo.scale-125.png",
      "sizes": "188x188"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Wide310x150Logo.scale-400.png",
      "sizes": "1240x600"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Wide310x150Logo.scale-200.png",
      "sizes": "620x300"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png",
      "sizes": "310x150"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Wide310x150Logo.scale-150.png",
      "sizes": "465x225"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Wide310x150Logo.scale-125.png",
      "sizes": "388x188"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square310x310Logo.scale-400.png",
      "sizes": "1240x1240"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square310x310Logo.scale-200.png",
      "sizes": "620x620"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png",
      "sizes": "310x310"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square310x310Logo.scale-150.png",
      "sizes": "465x465"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square310x310Logo.scale-125.png",
      "sizes": "388x388"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square44x44Logo.scale-400.png",
      "sizes": "176x176"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square44x44Logo.scale-200.png",
      "sizes": "88x88"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square44x44Logo.scale-100.png",
      "sizes": "44x44"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square44x44Logo.scale-150.png",
      "sizes": "66x66"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square44x44Logo.scale-125.png",
      "sizes": "55x55"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-256.png",
      "sizes": "256x256"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-48.png",
      "sizes": "48x48"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24.png",
      "sizes": "24x24"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-16.png",
      "sizes": "16x16"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-256_altform-unplated.png",
      "sizes": "256x256"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-48_altform-unplated.png",
      "sizes": "48x48"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-24_altform-unplated.png",
      "sizes": "24x24"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/Square44x44Logo.targetsize-16_altform-unplated.png",
      "sizes": "16x16"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/StoreLogo.scale-400.png",
      "sizes": "200x200"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/StoreLogo.scale-200.png",
      "sizes": "100x100"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/StoreLogo.scale-150.png",
      "sizes": "75x75"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/StoreLogo.scale-125.png",
      "sizes": "63x63"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/StoreLogo.scale-100.png",
      "sizes": "50x50"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/StoreLogo.png",
      "sizes": "50x50"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/SplashScreen.scale-400.png",
      "sizes": "2480x1200"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/SplashScreen.scale-200.png",
      "sizes": "1240x600"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/SplashScreen.scale-150.png",
      "sizes": "930x450"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/SplashScreen.scale-125.png",
      "sizes": "775x375"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows10/SplashScreen.scale-100.png",
      "sizes": "620x300"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windows-smallsquare-24-24.png",
      "sizes": "24x24"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windows-smallsquare-30-30.png",
      "sizes": "30x30"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windows-smallsquare-42-42.png",
      "sizes": "42x42"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windows-smallsquare-54-54.png",
      "sizes": "54x54"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windows-splashscreen-1116-540.png",
      "sizes": "1116x540"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windows-splashscreen-868-420.png",
      "sizes": "868x420"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windows-splashscreen-620-300.png",
      "sizes": "620x300"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windows-squarelogo-270-270.png",
      "sizes": "270x270"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windows-squarelogo-210-210.png",
      "sizes": "210x210"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windows-squarelogo-150-150.png",
      "sizes": "150x150"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windows-squarelogo-120-120.png",
      "sizes": "120x120"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windows-storelogo-90-90.png",
      "sizes": "90x90"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windows-storelogo-70-70.png",
      "sizes": "70x70"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windows-storelogo-50-50.png",
      "sizes": "50x50"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windowsphone-appicon-106-106.png",
      "sizes": "106x106"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windowsphone-appicon-62-62.png",
      "sizes": "62x62"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windowsphone-appicon-44-44.png",
      "sizes": "44x44"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windowsphone-mediumtile-360-360.png",
      "sizes": "360x360"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windowsphone-mediumtile-210-210.png",
      "sizes": "210x210"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windowsphone-mediumtile-150-150.png",
      "sizes": "150x150"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windowsphone-smalltile-170-170.png",
      "sizes": "170x170"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windowsphone-smalltile-99-99.png",
      "sizes": "99x99"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windowsphone-smalltile-71-71.png",
      "sizes": "71x71"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windowsphone-storelogo-120-120.png",
      "sizes": "120x120"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windowsphone-storelogo-70-70.png",
      "sizes": "70x70"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/windows/windowsphone-storelogo-50-50.png",
      "sizes": "50x50"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/android/android-launchericon-512-512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/android/android-launchericon-192-192.png",
      "sizes": "192x192",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/android/android-launchericon-144-144.png",
      "sizes": "144x144",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/android/android-launchericon-96-96.png",
      "sizes": "96x96",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/android/android-launchericon-72-72.png",
      "sizes": "72x72",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/android/android-launchericon-48-48.png",
      "sizes": "48x48",
      "purpose": "any maskable"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/ios/ios-appicon-1024-1024.png",
      "sizes": "1024x1024"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/ios/ios-appicon-180-180.png",
      "sizes": "180x180"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/ios/ios-appicon-152-152.png",
      "sizes": "152x152"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/ios/ios-appicon-120-120.png",
      "sizes": "120x120"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/ios/ios-appicon-76-76.png",
      "sizes": "76x76"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/ios/ios-launchimage-750-1334.png",
      "sizes": "750x1334"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/ios/ios-launchimage-1334-750.png",
      "sizes": "1334x750"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/ios/ios-launchimage-1242-2208.png",
      "sizes": "1242x2208"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/ios/ios-launchimage-2208-1242.png",
      "sizes": "2208x1242"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/ios/ios-launchimage-640-960.png",
      "sizes": "640x960"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/ios/ios-launchimage-640-1136.png",
      "sizes": "640x1136"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/ios/ios-launchimage-1536-2048.png",
      "sizes": "1536x2048"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/ios/ios-launchimage-2048-1536.png",
      "sizes": "2048x1536"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/ios/ios-launchimage-768-1024.png",
      "sizes": "768x1024"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/ios/ios-launchimage-1024-768.png",
      "sizes": "1024x768"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/chrome/chrome-extensionmanagementpage-48-48.png",
      "sizes": "48x48"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/chrome/chrome-favicon-16-16.png",
      "sizes": "16x16"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/chrome/chrome-installprocess-128-128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/firefox/firefox-marketplace-512-512.png",
      "sizes": "512x512"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/firefox/firefox-marketplace-128-128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/firefox/firefox-general-256-256.png",
      "sizes": "256x256"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/firefox/firefox-general-128-128.png",
      "sizes": "128x128"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/firefox/firefox-general-90-90.png",
      "sizes": "90x90"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/firefox/firefox-general-64-64.png",
      "sizes": "64x64"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/firefox/firefox-general-48-48.png",
      "sizes": "48x48"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/firefox/firefox-general-32-32.png",
      "sizes": "32x32"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/icons/firefox/firefox-general-16-16.png",
      "sizes": "16x16"
    }
  ],
  "categories": [
    "timer",
    "tools",
    "alarms",
    "productivity",
    "utilities"
  ],
  "screenshots": [
    {
      "src": "img/previews/preview1.webp",
      "sizes": "1280x720",
      "type": "image/webp"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/previews/preview2.webp",
      "sizes": "1280x720",
      "type": "image/webp"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/previews/preview3.webp",
      "sizes": "1280x720",
      "type": "image/webp"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/previews/preview4.webp",
      "sizes": "1280x720",
      "type": "image/webp"
    },
    {
      "src": "img/previews/preview5.webp",
      "sizes": "1280x720",
      "type": "image/webp"
    }
  ]
}
```

This is my GitHub repo:

https://github.com/FANMixco/toastmasters-timer-material-design

And this is the link where you can test it:

https://fanmixco.github.io/toastmasters-timer-material-design/

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

**P.S.:**

- I have tested on different phones (Android 7 and Android 10 with the latest version of Chrome for Android available, 90.0.4430.210).
- A friend of mine has also tested on his phone running Android 10 and Chrome, and he had never opened the link before. He experienced the same issue.

Comment: Has someone attempted it on a phone you have not yet tested with? Could be something you have not removed from previous attempts/installs.

Comment: Hi @Mathias, a friend of mine tested in his phone. Also, the pics come from my phone where Chrome is not my main browser.